# Fetchmail not writing to log

Tags: fetchmail

I'm setting up fetchmail for use with Request Tracker on a RHEL 8 server. It's not working and I'm unable to troubleshoot because it doesn't appear to be writing to `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/fetchmail.log`. How do I get it to write to one of these logs?

Here's my `/etc/fetchmailrc`:

```
set daemon 60
set invisible
set postmaster administrator
set syslog
set logfile /var/log/fetchmail.log
poll pop.gmail.com protocol pop3 port 995 username "user@example.com" password "xxxxxx" ssl mda "/var/www/html/requesttracker/bin/rt-mailgate --queue YLN --action correspond --url https://subdomain.example.com" nokeep
```

I restart fetchmail after each fetchmailrc edit. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: I tried this (I had already touched fetchmail.log with root:root access) and restarted fetchmail:

```
set daemon 60
set invisible
set postmaster administrator
set logfile /var/log/fetchmail.log
poll pop.gmail.com protocol pop3 port 995 username "user@example.com" password "xxxxxx" ssl mda "/var/www/html/requesttracker/bin/rt-mailgate --queue YLN --action correspond --url https://subdomain.example.com" nokeep
```

Nothing. The fetchmail.log file remains empty.

So then I tried this and restarted fetchmail:

```
set daemon 60
set invisible
set postmaster administrator
set syslog
poll pop.gmail.com protocol pop3 port 995 username "user@example.com" password "xxxxxx" ssl mda "/var/www/html/requesttracker/bin/rt-mailgate --queue YLN --action correspond --url https://subdomain.example.com" nokeep
```

Again nothing. There are sendmail entries in the maillog file from my testing but they're from hours ago.

I figured out to run `sudo env LC_ALL=C fetchmail -vvv  --nodetach --nosyslog -f /etc/fetchmailrc` to see what's happening when it connects with Google. As it turns out, I didn't have one of those special passwords that Google needs to generate for you. If you're in this boat, see https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords.

Comment: I thought `fetchmail` used `LOG_MAIL` as the facility.  The default RHEL8 configuration would send those messages to `/var/log/maillog`.  And I think `set logfile` may override `set syslog`.   For the log file you need to ensure it already exists and is writeable by the user running `fetchmail`.

Comment: From the man page: `set logfile -L Name of a file to append error and status  messages  to.  Only effective in daemon mode and if  fetch‐mail   detaches.    If  effective, overrides set syslog. Note that the logfile **must exist before** fetchmail is run, you can use the touch(1) command with the filename as its sole argument to create it.`